# Image of linear projection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety (i.e. zariski closed), and let $\pi : X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$ a linear projection ($\pi$ is not in every point of $X$ defined).

Under which conditions is the image $\pi(X)$ zariski closed? What criterions are known?